# React error when following tutorial

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to follow a pluralsight tutorial for getting started with react js.
The point of the tutorial is that clicking on the button results in an incremented value for the button. I followed the exact code the person the in the tutorial had but I cannot figure out why the button wont increment. Here is the [link to the plunk for this tutorial.](http://plnkr.co/edit/jsMsUYkCbnN5sbMqAUTH?p=preview)

My guess is that maybe there is something wrong with my

```
handleClick: function(){
    this.setState({ counter: this.state.counter+1 });
  },
```

function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your

```
onclick
```

should be

```
onClick
```

instead.

Change that and it should work.

Also, you might want to use

```
ReactDOM.render
```

instead of

```
React.render
```

Refer to this https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/props-in-getInitialState-as-anti-pattern.html

Comment: Be more careful next time:)